# Automatically include all php files in a child theme directory

Tags: functions, child-theme, include

I'm currently using a custom child theme across multiple sites, and would like to modularise particular custom features (e.g. ecommerce) by separating them into individual php files, and including the relevant ones as needed (without making them into plugins), since otherwise it's difficult to keep track of the customisations in each file across multiple variations of the child theme.

To do this, I'd like to be able to copy particular php files into a folder in the child theme, and for these to be included automatically. How would I achieve this?I've tried [several solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599670/how-to-include-all-php-files-from-a-directory), but they don't seem to work in this context. Here's an example of a code I used:

```
function include_all_php($folder){
 foreach (glob("{$folder}/*.php") as $filename)
 {
    include $filename;
 }
}
include_all_php("includes"); // "includes" is the name of the folder in the child theme
```

Comment: Move the shared files to plugins or libraries, and learn how to use an auto-loader.

Comment: Include the actual code you have tried if it is different to the linked solution.

Comment: @majick OK, I've included an example of the code I tried.

Comment: @bosco That's what I'm here to find out. Please see the new code example above.

Comment: @toscho Could you suggest some resources for looking into those? Thanks.

Comment: See [the PHP manual on `spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) plus comments for the **basics**, [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for the current de facto **naming standard**, and [Composer autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) for the most used **tool** for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `glob` needs the *current working directory* to work, so you could try passing the full path of the file to the existing function you have...

```
include_all_php(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes');
```

Or set the current working directory first:

```
setcwd(dirname(__FILE__).'/');
include_all_php('includes');
```

Alternatively you could also use `scandir`:

```
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/';
$files = scandir($filepath);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // match the file extension to .php
    if (substr($file,-4,4) == '.php') {include($filepath.$file);}
}
```